# Group Action and "nice" Approximation!

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, representation-theory

Studying the action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ is naturally the same as looking at the group homomorphism $\alpha: G \rightarrow Perm(X)$. So, for a given group $G$, classifying all sets $X$, on which the group $G$ acts, is the same as asking about the existence of the group homomorphism above, for the aforementioned sets $X$.

Since the question in such generality may not be mathematically feasible to ask (or possible to answer), we put some extra assumptions on the sets $X$, and that seems to be the cradle of Representation Theory of Groups.
Meanwhile, if we put the additional assumptions over $X$ cunningly enough, they drastically shoot $X$ from a humble set without any specific structures (and even a precise definition) to a vector space $V$,  with those many spiffy properties.

Although this seems to be a natural choice, specially after decades of works in this realm, I was wondering if we could possibly step back and when we want to equip $X$ with some additional structures, do it step by step. 
Namely, could we ask the same question about all those mathematical structures between a set $X$ and a vector space $V$, once the group $G$ is fixed?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what kind of answers you are looking for. But I will comment that there are many possibilities here. A common theme is to add a bit of structure to $X$, and to insist that the group action respects that structure. For example, if $X$ is also a differentiable manifold, it is natural to require that $G$ acts via diffeomorphisms. Similarly, if $X$ is an algebraic variety (and $G$ is an algebraic group), then we want $G$ to act via isomorphisms.

Comment: (cont'd) The rep theory of algebraic groups took leaps, when we started realizing them as emerging from the functorial action of $G$ on the sheaf cohomology of such projective varieties $X$. The least bit of structure could be to put a useful topology on $X$. Not sure whether that is enough though. My point may be that representation theory is something of a 2-way street. We study both $X$ and $G$, and the way they restrict each other.

Comment: Dear Jyrki, thanks for your comments.
Actually, the main reason for asking the question, as you partly addressed in your comments, was to understand if the action of $G$ on sets $X$ with different (weaker) conditions have also been studied. 
For instance, what about the case when $X$ is a module over an arbitrary ring $R$, which may or may not be commutative.
What about the case where $X$ is simply a group, not necessarily abelian. Or even weaker, what if $X$ is a monoid?
It seems natural to put some assumptions on the set $X$ and then try to study the action of $G$.

Comment: However, what is unnatural (at least to me) is the approach we choose and the assumptions we put on the set $X$. Namely, starting with a set, we should skip many structures to reach vector spaces, and this large gap between these structures demands justification.
Something irritating is that almost all of the texts suddenly jump to the widely accepted settings (in this case vector spaces) without any insightful comments on the possibility of studying the same topic in different settings, or justifying that the setting they have chosen is better than the others for certain reasons.

Comment: Action of a group on an abelian group is studied e.g. in class field theory, when $X$ is the multiplicative group of an algebraic number field (or some structure derived from that) and $G$ is the Galois group. Those are modules over the group ring $\Bbb{Z}[G]$. I need to think about your last comment to be able to say anything useful :-)